# JSON feed display on a website

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to get a JSON feed be loaded on a website I'm working on.  I've looked around online, and there seems to be plenty of examples, but little information on how to return a remote webpage's JSON as a object.

Currently I have the below test code I'm working on.

The JSON feed I'm trying to get into my webpage is;
http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/frostmourne/Group+Therapy/rating.tier13_10/json_rank

Current goal is just to view the returned JSON feed so I know its working, so I have been playing with the below snippet.

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();       
var wowprogress
//var xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // Commented out currently, use for IE
xhttp.open("GET","http://www.wowprogress.com/guild/us/frostmourne/Group+Therapy/rating.tier13_10/json_rank",false);
xhttp.send();

var myJSONString = xhttp.innerTEXT;
alert(myJSONString);    

var myObject = eval("(" + myJSONString + ")");
var myValue = myObject.realm_rank;
    alert(myValue);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, or the right direction to investigate further.

Thanks :)

Comment: The same origin policy prevents you from making AJAX request to another domain. You will probably have to implement a proxy or JSONP wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you're running into cross-domain issues. browsers by default don't allow you to use XHR (ajax) to fetch documents that are located on a different domain than the host page (this also includes sub-domains).

there are some workarounds:

- [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) : This is likely not an option, as it requires configuration on a server that you don't own
- [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) : This may be an option, if the remote server understands it. It is essentially a JSON response wrapped in a function call, so that you can include it on your page as plain JS.
- Proxy : create a proxy on the server so that you can make ajax requests to the same domain. Ben Alman has a simple example [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/docs/files/ba-simple-proxy-php.html).

in short, you are going to need another transport mechanism to be able to load remote documents on to your page via JS.

i hope that helps! cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First, never use eval.  Its horribly insecure.

Instead use JSON.parse(your_json) to convert your data into an object literal.  When you are done with it and want to package it for transport then JSON.stringify(your_json);